# How to give footer background image an extremely rare chance to change to a different image upon refreshing site?

Tags: html, css, footer

Something like this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var images = ['OUT01ari.jpg', 'OUT02adobe.jpg', 'OUT03alife.jpg', 'OUT04chinup.jpg', 'OUT05datenightwinecologne.jpg', 'OUT06officechair.jpg', 'OUT07printer.jpg', 'OUT08whitewall.jpg', 'OUT09umbrella.jpg', 'OUT10converse.jpg', 'OUT11wardrobebar.jpg'];
 $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
</script>
```

but I need it to be biased towards a particular image. Like, 90% chance for the first image and 10% for the other. Tried looking it up, but I've only managed to find codes that make it purely random (50/50 for 2 images, 25/25/25/25 for 4 images, etc). And as the title says, it's meant to be the background of a footer. I don't know if that changes anything or not, just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your can do it in 3 lines of code:

```
var selected = images[0];  //by default take the first image
if(Math.random()*10>=9){  //if 10% of probability happens
   selected = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*8)+1];  //take the random image from the rest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
// return a random number between zero and max, inclusive
// ie if max = 2, number could be 0, 1, or 2
getRandom: function (max) {
    var multiplier = max + 1;
    var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier);
    return ranNum;
}
```

and then:

```
    var randomNumber = Helpers.getRandom(9);

    if (randomNumber === 9)
        // we'll get in here 10% of the time
```